# How to compile a Web Site Project directly out of Visual Studio without aspnet_compiler?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, vs-web-site-project, aspnet-compiler

I have a Web Site project and want my .aspx and .cs to be compiled. For this I am using a the aspnet compiler like this:

```
aspnet_compiler -v /My_Site -p c:\site_published_with_Visual_Studio c:\site_compiled_with_aspnet_compiler
```

This means, that I have to publish my website with Visual Studio 2010 first and then open a command line to call aspnet_compiler.

Is there a way to compile a web site project directly with Visual Studio 2010, maybe by clicking around instead of using a command line? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Have you looked at [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx)?

Comment: If yuo right click on the project or solution node, you should see the option to "Publish Web Site". If you right click this it will ask you where/how you want to publish, and will take care of the rest for you. I generally publish to a folder on my file system then upload the site using FTP, but there are options to publish directly to the web server, for example.

Comment: @ dash : I am publishing my web site exactly like this, but it won't compile my files. For this I have to manually work with apsnet_compiler.

Comment: What happens when you run the publish? Do you get an error in the Output window? Have you checked the project properties to make sure you are building all properties in the solution?

Comment: @ dash : I am not getting any errors. I made a screenshot of my project properties and the publishing window: http://www.abload.de/img/unbenanntui3ql.png (I have a German Visual Studio installation)

Answer (score 0):

You may use `Publish WebSite` wizard - Build Menu + Publish WebSite. Have a look at MSDN article - [How to: Deploy a Web Site Project by Using the Publish Web Site Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20yh9f1b.aspx).

Comment: I not sure what I am doing wrong, but the Publish Website wizard doesn't give me the necessary options, see http://www.abload.de/img/unbenanntui3ql.png